# can't import traceback in QGIS 3.2.2

Tags: python, qgis-3, importerror

I have compiled QGIS from branch QGIS-release-3.2 on bionic beaver (ubuntu 18.04), the ccmake step detects python 3.6 path (/usr/bin/python3.6) and all the compilation goes OK

Starting QGIS 3.2.2 the following error pops up

[image: QGIS cant import traceback]

Reporting that it can't import traceback, more interesting is that there is no indication of python interpreter and/or paths being used

Inside the python terminal I can do  `import qgis`  without problems.

Question: How can I fix this could it be that somewhere QGIS doesnt have python path properly set ???

Note: The OS (bionic beaver) was upgaded from xenial and sometimes strange things happen